React native RTL is forced on RTL devices
im i18n and i18nManager to handle LTR and RTL layout in my application with expo router
if the device system language is LTR(english for example), everything works wonders if i switch from RTL to LTR or LTR to RTL
if the device system language is RTL(arabic for example), then RTL is being forced no matter what language is chosen, i tried to do allowRTL(false) forceRTL(false), after that if i check i18Manager.isRTL it gives true no matter what, and the layout is RTL as i mentioned
what could be the issue and the fix if possible
Tried to Set device language to RTL arabic, and in App set language to English LTR
expected: layout to change from RTL to LTR
result: layout stuck on RTL even if language is LTR

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After doing I18nManager.allowRTL(false) and then I18nManager.forceRTL(false) you need to restart the app (with React Native Restart for example)
